# MAC address in u_char[6] from buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[s]

Tags: c, linux, ethernet, mac-address

I need to get my routers MAC address in u_char[6] format from the buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[s] format given by ifr structure.

Comment: so `buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[s]` is your character buffer right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
for( s = 0; s < 5; s++ )
  {
      printf("%.2X:", (unsigned char)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[s]);
  }
```

Comment: To `printf()` 1 byte the conversion specifier should be prefixed by the appropriate length modifier `"hh"`, to become `"hhX"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `cat /sys/class/net/ethX/address`, where X=0,1,2...

```
FILE * output= popen("cat /sys/class/net/ethX/address");
if(output)
{
    //Write your code here
    pclose(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might wants to convert 6 byte integral Macaddress to 6 byte char string, you have to take care for networkByteOrder also.